# Difficulty getting two Animation Node Trees to Execute concurrently

Tags: animation-nodes, solidify-modifier

**Setup:**
I have two rigged characters in my scene. I am using two Animation Node trees, one for each, to control the thickness of their solidify modifier outlines based on their distance to the Active Camera.
**Problem:**
Only one of the trees ever executes.
I have confirmed either tree works by themselves in other scenes.
**Question:**
I would like to know what I am doing wrong and why when both Node Trees are present only one of them executes ? I cannot tell where the conflict lies and I get no errors or warnings.
The Viewer node values actually update as I move the Camera around all the way down the tree. It just never updates on the actual character's Modifier.
[image]

[image]

Comment: i just tried it out. Animation nodes can execute two trees without problems (proof: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEE0N.gif) . So i am sure the problem is somewhere else. I hate to "theoretical" solve problems, because you cannot be sure it is the right solution so i recommend providing your blend file. But...by just looking at your trees i could be possible that one tree overwrites just the result of the other tree (because both write to the same custom property)...but without trying it out...this is just a guess.

Comment: I read in another post that Animation Node Trees can override each other, but it was a case where both trees were affecting the same object. in My example both trees process two different sets of geometry so I'm not sure how that works. I'm using Linked rigs in my scene so I'll have to setup a simplified file to submit. Will update when I have it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working but it needs to be set it up this way:
You need to append and duplicate the node tree completely blank and then fill everything out for each character. I used to have one version of the node tree already filled out for each character and I thought I'd append each characters tree with them but that does not work.
I've updated my default scene to have the blank node tree (all executions OFF).
 I just copy/paste the nodes from the blank tree into new trees as needed and then fill them out in the scene.
Also remember to delete the extra scene that gets appended with the blank tree !